# Send PDF as attachment using React and .Net Core Web Api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, email

I found alot of outdated options on the web so Just wandering what should be the best approach to convert DOM, as an PDF attachment and then send it via email.
I am using React as Front-end and .Net Core web Api as backend.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> Download jsPDF from [Github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) Include these scripts below:
>
> ```
> jspdf.js
> jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
> jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
> jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js
> ```
>
> If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an
> ID, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of jsPDF.
> Therefore your HTML should look like this:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
>     <div>
>       <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
>     </div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in
> a PopUp:
>
> ```
> var doc = new jsPDF();          
> var elementHandler = {
>   '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
>     return true;
>   }
> };
> var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
> doc.fromHTML(
>     source,
>     15,
>     15,
>     {
>       'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
>     });
>
> doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
> ```
>
> One very important thing to add is that you lose all your style
> information (CSS). Luckily jsPDF is able to nicely format h1, h2, h3
> etc., which was enough for my purposes. Additionally it will only
> print text within text nodes, which means that it will not print the
> values of textareas and the like. Example:
>
> ```
> <body>
>   <ul>
>     <!-- This is printed as the element contains a textnode -->        
>     <li>Print me!</li>
>   </ul>
>   <div>
>     <!-- This is not printed because jsPDF doesn't deal with the value attribute -->
>     <input type="textarea" value="Please print me, too!">
>   </div>
> </body>
> ```

Attach the pdf and send emails with the help of this [link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-send-an-email-with-image-attachment-in-node-js-react-657479d49587)